# What is the maximum precision with Decimal in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, decimal, precision, max

I need to retain upto 17 decimal places. What is the appropriate precision with Decimal in SQL server 2005 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends how many values you want left of the decimal point, probably 17. So precision should be 17 + 17 = 34, and scale = 17.

So long as your scale is 17 and your precision is >= 17 (whatever your precision - scale is how many digits you can have left of the decimal point).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: But When I gave Decimal(20,17)...it shows arithmetic overflow

Comment: Does Decimal(20,17) means ...20 integer before the decimal point and 17 integers after decimal point?

Comment: No it mean 20 digits over all and 17 after leaving 3 before.

Comment: I have a value..Decimal(17,11). when I multiply this value with another decimal...i need to maintain the deimal values

Comment: The question specifies SQL Server 2005, but 10+ years later the link for the latest version may prove useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old, but here is the answer that I found useful:

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187746(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

---

> In SQL Server, the default maximum precision of numeric and decimal data types is 38. In earlier versions of SQL Server, the default maximum is 28.

---